# gt-tools on Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss, geotools

I am working on a legacy project that runs on JBoss 7.1.1 and I am using the geotools library (14.5 version).

When the the project is deployed I get a lot of warnings like this

```
 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.WarpTransform2D$Provider' for service type 'org.geotools.referencing.operation.MathTransformProvider'
```

and when I am trying to execute code related to geotools I get back

```
Problem asking Directory of spatial files (shapefiles) if it can process request:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.canProcess(Ljava/util/Map;[Lorg/geotools/data/DataAccessFactory$Param;)Z: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.canProcess(Ljava/util/Map;[Lorg/geotools/data/DataAccessFactory$Param;)Z
```

I suspect that is a problem with some library dependency but I do not know how to proceed to fix it.

The project uses ant as a build tool. It builds an EAR package that when expanded contains a `lib` folder with all the relevant libraries, including the ones reported as problematic above. I see nothing worth mentioning in the included `MANIFEST.MF` of the EAR, JAR, and WAR subpackages.

Any ideas how I can debug and solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things (and with out seeing the project dependencies it's hard to be sure which).

1. You may be missing a referencing jar - see the [FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html) for more details
2. You may have failed to handle the `META-INF/services` files correctly when adding jars to your WAR file and JAR files - see this [FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/faq.html) for details of this.
3. You might need so additional files to make JBOSS work see [this page](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/jboss/jboss_tutorial.html) to see how GeoServer (which is built using GeoTools) does it.

And, you may want to consider upgrading to a currently supported version like 23.x or 24.x.